# Rotating Cube by 90 degrees causes

Tags: unity, rotation

I'm making a game where I'd like the player to be able to rotate a cube by 90 degrees on the x or z axis by pressing a button. I've gotten fairly far along in the process, but I've run into two problems here. #1. When using the following code, the x-rotation will sometimes get stuck toggling between 90 and -180 degrees when scrolling forward. #2. I'd like to be able to rotate the cube always to the players perspective (for example when the player right clicks the cube will always rotate 90 degrees to *their* right, instead of wherever the z-axis has been repositioned by the other rotation). Any help with either of these issues would be greatly appreciated.

````
private void Update()
    {
        if(Input.mouseScrollDelta.y > 0 && !isRotating)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Roll90(new Vector3(90, 0, 0)));
        }
        if (Input.mouseScrollDelta.y < 0 && !isRotating)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Roll90(new Vector3(-90, 0, 0)));
        }
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !isRotating)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Roll90(new Vector3(0, 0, 90)));
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1) && !isRotating)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Roll90(new Vector3(0, 0, -90)));
        }
    }
    
    IEnumerator Roll90(Vector3 rot)
    {
        currentRotation = transform.eulerAngles;
        targetRotation = currentRotation + rot;
        isRotating = true;

        if(rot.x != 0)
        {
            while (currentRotation.x != targetRotation.x)
            {
                currentRotation.x = Mathf.MoveTowardsAngle(currentRotation.x, targetRotation.x, rotationTime * Time.deltaTime * 100);
                transform.eulerAngles = currentRotation;
                yield return null;
            }

            if(currentRotation.x != targetRotation.x)
            {
                transform.eulerAngles = targetRotation;
            }
        }

        if (rot.z != 0)
        {
            while (currentRotation.z != targetRotation.z)
            {
                currentRotation.z = Mathf.MoveTowardsAngle(currentRotation.z, targetRotation.z, rotationTime * Time.deltaTime * 100);
                transform.eulerAngles = currentRotation;
                yield return null;
            }

            if (currentRotation.z != targetRotation.z)
            {
                transform.eulerAngles = targetRotation;
            }
        }

        isRotating = false;
    }
```
````

Comment: If it helps at all, the 90, -180 problem only occurs on the x-axis

Comment: It sounds like a [Gimbal_lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock) problem for me. related: [how-to-avoid-gimbal-lock](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/51410/how-to-avoid-gimbal-lock)